# ValueError: time inversion found

Tags: python-3.x

I am using datetimerange to check if a date is in between two dates. Unfortunetaly I somehow got a strange error message without quitting the program or showing anything. Only when I ctrl+c it I get this error:

ValueError: time inversion found: 2021-09-02 14:48:34.796000+00:00 > 2021-08-25 12:27:20.603000+00:00

So this is the lines causing it:

> ```
>       try:
>         inRange = time_in_range(start_date, end_date, timestamp)
>       except:
>         inRange = time_in_range(end_date, start_date, timestamp)
> ```

I got the dates from elasticsearch logs and didn't get this before, so I don't know what has it caused. I even don't understand this error message.

Do you know what the problem is? THere is literally no information on the internet, so I think I ran into a bug or it is very obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Please, attach full code of the script

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that range is incorrect. I can easily trigger this message - see below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange
d1="2015-03-22T10:00:00+0900";
d2="2015-03-22T10:10:00+0900";
print(DateTimeRange(d1,d2).validate_time_inversion())
print(DateTimeRange(d2,d1).validate_time_inversion())
```

Output:

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/py/time_inversion_ex.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(DateTimeRange(d2,d1).validate_time_inversion())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datetimerange/__init__.py", line 272, in validate_time_inversion
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: time inversion found: 2015-03-22 10:10:00+09:00 > 2015-03-22 10:00:00+09:00
```